# cancelling a query in local Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a hung query and cannot terminate it.  I have tried the following to retrieve the pid:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active';
```

I have tried cancelling it using the following, but get

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request  SQL state: 57014

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(11392);
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(11392);
```

Below is the dashboard image and the database is active, but shouldn't the status be 'idle' instead of active?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You canceled your own statement. To determine the correct process ID, exclude your own session:

```
SELECT pid, query_start, query
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'active'
  AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: I placed a table to be recursively called in the function.  There wasn't any other active query running.